# python Caesar Cipher encrypt

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck on the Caesar cipher code.
I need to encrypt the msg the user inputs then have it shift between 1-25 depending on what is inputted.
My current code i have so far is

```
def encryptedmsg():
    text = input("Enter your message: ")
    shift = int(input("Enter a shift from 1-25"))
    cipher = ""
    for char in text:
        if not char.isalnum():
            continue
        if shift in range(1, 26):
            code = ord(char) + shift
            if code > ord("z"):
                code = ord("a")
            cipher += chr(code)

    print(cipher)

encryptedmsg()
```

I am trying to make it ignores the non-alphabet letter and still display them as is, within the output

when inputting, for example,

"The 123" with a shift of 25

i want the outcome,

"sdg 123"

but with my current code, it prints

"maaJKL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```py
if not char.isalnum():
  continue
```

to

```py
if not char.isalpha()
  cipher += char
  continue
```

That should only perform the shift on alphabetic characters, not alphanumeric, instead just appending the non-alpha characters.

The other question you asked, about why it's not getting the characters you want when it wraps around the end of the alphabet, is because you're just setting it to `ord("a")`. You need to reduce it back to within the range of the alphabet. For that, instead of

```py
code = ord("a")
```

you should have

```py
code -= 26
```

This still doesn't quite give you the output you want with your specific example, but that's because of the numeric values for the upper case characters. You need to include code to handle those separately, or else convert everything to lower case at the beginning.